# How to catch list ArrayAdapter NullPointerException if you don't know where exactly is the cause of the crash?

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I get bug report log where `ArrayAdapter` throws `NullPointer` exception but I cannot reproduce the issue in any way, plus the log doesn't point to any specific line of my Activity.

Here the error log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (ArrayAdapter.java:401)
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView (ArrayAdapter.java:369)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView (AbsListView.java:3073)
 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView (ListView.java:1945)
 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown (ListView.java:719)
 at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop (ListView.java:785)
 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1735)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout (AbsListView.java:2860)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1080)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
 at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild (ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.findFirstDependency (AppBarLayout.java:1361)
 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (AppBarLayout.java:1361)
 at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild (AppBarLayout.java:1361)
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:894)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1171)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout (PhoneWindow.java:3175)
 at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18014)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2784)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2477)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7616)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:686)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:622)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7422)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The problem seems related to `ListView`, my code structure is something like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter
    private ListView lv;
    List<String> mylist;
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist );
         refreshList();
         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    }

    ArrayList<String> populateList(){
        //create a new list arraylist of strings 
        //this method produces list with all non null values, so cannot be 
        //the cause of the issue
        ...
    }
    void refreshList(){
         mylist = populateList();
         arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    void clearList(){
        if(mylist!=null){
            mylist.clear();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

`populateList()` method returns always a list of all non-null elements and I haven't any idea of the cause of the error. How could I catch the issue?

Comment: where are you calling populateList? Also, where are you instantiating mylist?

Comment: @Levi Albuquerque mylist is instantiated with populatelist method that is called in refresh. Refresh is called the first time in onCreate() and then with some user actions

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint after you populate your list and inspect it in debugger, don't trust your gut about what it contains, checking it won't hurt.

Or go to `ArrayAdapter:401` (as told by stack trace) and see which statement is there, if it's `text.setText(item.toString());` then it's definitely a null item, otherwise you'll understand from statement there the source of your problem.

To open `ArrayAdapter` class in Android Studio/IDEA press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice, type the name of class and open it (or right-click on it and 'Go To->Declaration'), then navigate to line `401`, most probably it will be the source of your exception.

Sometimes you'll encounter situations when sources in your IDE do not correspond bytecode executed, then the safest choice would be to launch your application in emulator with SDK level corresponding to your sources.

Comment: The problem is that on my debugger such element isn't null in any case and doesn't crash, and I haven't any idea of what could be nullify It causing the problem for some users. For this reason I'm asking for a way to catch this error in some way so that I could debug It.

Comment: Do you know Android version of the device where the problem happens?

Comment: the problems happens randomly but isn't related to specific version I have received sporadic crash reports from various versions